# Python: Filter for Values where List A is Contained within List B

Tags: python

I have a list B:

```
pklFilenamesList = ['path\202206_DATASET_STACK_.pkl', 'path\202206_DATASET_OVER_.pkl',  'path\202206_DATASET_FLOW_.pkl']
```

I have a list A:

```
listing = ['OVER','FLOW']
```

Attempted filter:

```
pickle= [x for x in pklFilenamesList if x[0] in listing]
```

which is returning a blank list `[]`

Does anyone know how to filter for values from my List B contained in A?

Expected output:

```
pickle = ['path\202206_DATASET_OVER_.pkl',  'path\202206_DATASET_FLOW_.pkl']
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: `[b for b in b_arr for a in a_arr if a in b]`

Comment: Your mistake is that in your expression `x` is an element of `pklFilenamesList`, e.g. a string `path\202206_DATASET_STACK_.pkl` so `x[0]` is the first character of this list i.e. `p` and `"p" not in listing` so the result is `[]`. You want to do the opposite: for each element, check if `any` value of `listing` is `in` that element `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to check the value against every value on `listing`:

```
pickle = [x for x in pklFilenamesList if any(e in x for e in listing)]

print(pickle)
```

Result:

```
['path\x82206_DATASET_OVER_.pkl', 'path\x82206_DATASET_FLOW_.pkl']
```